# Grab variable from php URL string

Tags: php, string

What's the easiest way to grab a 6-character id from a string?

The id will always be after www.twitpic.com/ and will always be 6 characters.

```
e.g., $string = 'The url is http://www.twitpic.com/f1462i.  Enjoy.';
      $id = 'f1462i';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $string = "http://www.twitpic.com/f1462i" ;
  $id = substr($string,strpos($string, 'twitpic.com')+strlen('twitpic.com')+1,6) ;
  echo $id ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. Complete working code without `regex` :

```
<?php
$string = 'The url is http://www.twitpic.com/f1462i.  Enjoy.';
$id = substr($string, strpos($string, 'http://www.twitpic.com/')+23, 6);
echo $id;   //output: f1462i
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("@twitpic\.com/(\w{6})@", "The url is http://www.twitpic.com/f1462i.  Enjoy.", $m);
$id = $m[1];
```

Comment: -1: Do not use regexes when you can avoid them, they are a performance killer.

Comment: @greg0ire: Why are you downvoting the *answer* when it was the OP who tagged the question "regex"?

Comment: @Alan Moore: because I didn't read the tags... I would cancel this if I could but it seems to be too late. I retag the question, regexes have nothing to do with this.